# Use Cursor variable to insert with a loop in a store procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I have a store procedure and I need to take all id´s from a table and insert new rows in other table with those id´s but i dont´t understand well the function cursor

```
PROCEDURE INSERTMDCGENERAL AS

 idCat NUMERIC;
 CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT ID_CAT_FILTROS_TALENTO into idCat FROM MDC_CAT_FILTROS_TALENTO;

  BEGIN 

    FOR v_reg IN cur LOOP
      INSERT INTO MDC_FILTROS_TALENTO(ID_FILTRO,ID_CAT_FILTROS_TALENTO)
               VALUES(SEC_MDC_FILTROS_TALENTO.NextVal,idCat);    
    END LOOP;

COMMIT;

END INSERTMDCGENERAL;
```

Comment: Why are you using a cursor? Just insert your select statement...

Comment: There are to many rows in the table MDC_CAT_FILTROS_TALENTO, I read that I can use cursor to go throw all the records

Comment: A cursor will be _a lot_ slower because you have to process it row-by-row. If you have to split it then something like BULK COLLECT on parallel processing would be better. Consider whether you really have to do any of this though. How many records are there in the table and how long does the standard insert take?

Comment: You are doing lots of individual inserts, which will just be slower than a single `insert ... select`. If you're running out of rollback/undo with a single insert (all I can think you mean by 'too big') then this won't help as it is; it can be modified to avoid that problem but it would be a patch, your DB should be sized to deal with the work you need it to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is rarely any point in doing anything more complex than:

```
PROCEDURE INSERTMDCGENERAL AS
BEGIN 

      INSERT INTO MDC_FILTROS_TALENTO 
           (ID_FILTRO,ID_CAT_FILTROS_TALENTO)
      SELECT SEC_MDC_FILTROS_TALENTO.NextVal
             , ID_CAT_FILTROS_TALENTO 
      FROM MDC_CAT_FILTROS_TALENTO;

      COMMIT;

END INSERTMDCGENERAL;
```

This should work in most cases.  Only if you are dealing with millions of rows is it likely that you will need to embellish this.  Even then you should not use a cursor loop and Row-By-Row processing: that is vastly more inefficient.

Comment: What about if I'm working with millions of rows? What is the better way to do this?

Comment: @Angel - are you, as a DataStage ETL specialist, asking that as a serious question?

Comment: Customer only want to use a pl/sql - cursor of Oracle, so yes

Comment: It will be part of the tasks for the DBA, but I would like to know what is the best way to do this

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are expecting...

```
PROCEDURE INSERTMDCGENERAL AS
 idCat NUMERIC;
 CURSOR cur IS  SELECT ID_CAT_FILTROS_TALENTO FROM MDC_CAT_FILTROS_TALENTO;

  BEGIN 
  open cur;
  loop
    fetch cur into idCat;
    exit when cur%notfound;
      INSERT INTO MDC_FILTROS_TALENTO(ID_FILTRO,ID_CAT_FILTROS_TALENTO)
               VALUES(SEC_MDC_FILTROS_TALENTO.NextVal,idCat);    
  END LOOP;
  close cur;
 COMMIT;

 END INSERTMDCGENERAL;
```

Comment: The OPEN/FETCH/CLOSE method will be slower since it does not use automatic bulk collect.

Comment: @jonearles it may be true but for the given circumstances it will be the better option. Else the best way is to avoid the cursor all together and go with basic method as given in 1st answer above